# Wait for Angular2 to render following property change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm currently developing an Angular2 application and am facing an issue regarding property changes and life cycle events.

## Example

Let's say that I have a simple template that is being rendered based on a property. I would like `#container` to stay hidden until the rendering is done, then add the `visible` class to it to have it show up.

```
<div id="container">
    <p *ngFor="let value in values">
        {{value}}
    </p>
</div>
```

## The problem

The problem is that `.visible` defines a transition, too, and the browser simply cannot handle Angular's rendering and the transition at the same time, so it quite simply stops for a moment, and then the `#container` just snaps in.

## What I have tried

Setting a long enough time for the transition solves the problem, but I wouldn't want to change that.

I have also looked into [Angular's life cycle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html) hooks, but none of them seems to match my specific need.

## Goals

I would like to be notified once Angular has finished rendering the contents of `#container`, so that I can add the `visible` class while no other work is being done, and have a smooth transition.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no support for that requirement. You can extend the `NgFor` class and fire an event when updates are done. No need to create a feature request. The last was just rejected ;-)

Comment: If you are populating `values` in some event handler callback, try adding a `setTimeout(someFn, 0)` after you populate `values`.  Have `someFn` toggle a visibility property:  `<div id="container" [class.myTransitionClas]="isVisible">`.  This should allow the CSS transition to start after the browser rendered the list.

Comment: In a nutshell, use `setTimeout(onRender, 0);` and do whatever you need to inside `onRender()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark Rajcok's comment got me thinking and I have looked up different methods to take action at the next possible moment, including `setTimeout`, `requestAnimationFrame`, and finally `setImmediate`.

I have decided to settle for `setImmediate` as it seems to be the most straightforward way to defer an action to the next browser tick.

**Be aware, that `setImmediate` is merely a proposal right now, and I am only able to use it because `core-js` implements it already. It might not even become a standard in the future.**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/setImmediate

> Note: This method is not expected to become standard, and is only implemented by recent builds of Internet Explorer and Node.js 0.10+. It meets resistance both from Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit (Google/Apple).